# Programmatic Downloading Email Attachments C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, email

Is their anyway i can programmatic download all attachment sent to a specified email address in c#?

Any help on this matter would be greatly appriciated

```
var client = new Pop3Client();
        client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
        client.Authenticate("email", "email password");
        var count = client.GetMessageCount();
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
        {
            var message = client.GetMessage(i);
            ListBox.Items.Add(message.Headers.Subject);

}
```

~ Ben

Comment: Yes, you can. What exactly is your question and what have you tried?

Comment: You'll have to explain what type of email service or server you're working with.  Eg. gmail, POP, IMAP.  Also some code you're using to read emails would help.

Comment: Idealy i would like to use gmail and everything iv tried hasent worked. Also please find the updated question with the code im using to read the email.